# Unicode Support in MFC Controls

Tags: c++, windows, unicode, mfc

I'm exploring converting an existing MFC app from MBCS to Unicode, and I'm compiling a simple starter app in Unicode mode to check out how edit controls, for example, behave differently in Unicode/W or MBCS/A mode.

But I'm getting some strange results.

If I enter <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>1702</kbd> into Word, for example, I get the Arabic character (ڦ) which is expected from the Unicode table.

But if I enter <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>1702</kbd> into an edit control in the Unicode MFC app, I get a superscript "a" (ª) instead.  This is the same behaviour that I get from the existing MBCS app.

This second behaviour also happens in Word (2007) if I use File-Open and enter <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>1702</kbd> in the Filename field.  But it comes through properly if I enter it in the Font combo in the Ribbon.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows disables hex-numpad by default. You must enable it and enter the value using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd><kbd>Hex value</kbd>

How to enable it:

- [Insert Unicode characters via the keyboard?](https://superuser.com/q/47420/241386)
- [How to enter Unicode characters in Microsoft Windows](http://www.fileformat.info/tip/microsoft/enter_unicode.htm)

---

About the reason why <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>1702</kbd> produces **ª**

[Alt codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alt_code) are generally limited to [ANSI or OEM code pages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_code_page) only and **won't work for code points larger than 255**. A *few* apps (like MS Word as you experienced) do support larger values, which means <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>1702</kbd> will produce [U+06A6](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/06a6/index.htm) (*Arabic letter peheh* = ڦ) as expected (1702 = 0x06A6). Some other apps just throw away any digits after the third one. But by default in almost all applications if you input any larger values then **only the low byte of the real value is taken** as the code point, i.e. modulo 256

So pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>1702</kbd> will be equivalent to <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>166</kbd> because 1702 ≡ 166 (mod 256). When you run US Windows which uses [code page 437](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437) for the OEM code page then **the character at code point 166 is ª**

Comment: Excellent, thanks, I had set the EnableHexNumpad registry value, but didn't realise it needed a reboot to activate it.  Now all working as expected.